# SourceLink in VSTS

Tags: sourcelink

I'm trying to integrate SourceLink into Visual Studio Team Services by using https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink
I have problems with it since the package seems unable to parse the URL of a VSTS repository.

```
Build started 8/22/2017 11:58:18 AM.
 1>Project "D:\Repos\Core\classic-stats\src\Acme.Stats\Acme.Stats.csproj" on node 1 (Build target(s)).
 1>SourceLinkCreate:
     git rev-parse --show-toplevel
     D:/Repos/Core/classic-stats
     git config --get remote.origin.url
     https://acme.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Core/_git/classic-stats
     git rev-parse HEAD
     8c6a68b325cf10b67332aa2ea15db952a88d027d
     SourceLinkUrl:
     unable to convert OriginUrl: https://acme.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Core/_git/classic-stats
 1>Done Building Project "D:\Repos\Core\classic-stats\src\Acme.Stats\Acme.Stats.csproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

AFAIK there's only support for GitHub and BitBucket, am I right?
Has anybody been able to integrate this into TFS builds?
Thanks

Comment: Out of the box, it has built in support for GitHub and BitBucket to create the `SourceLinkUrl` from the `remote.origin.url`. You can set the SourceLinkUrl if you know what it should be. If that is a private repository, it will not work just yet. See known issues. https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink#known-issues

Comment: Check https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink it has support for VSTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Skorunka stated in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814563/sourcelink-in-vsts#comment89849019_45814563), SourceLink now has support for VSTS (recently renamed *Azure DevOps*)

Install the <s>[Microsoft.SourceLink.Vsts.Git](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SourceLink.Vsts.Git)</s> [Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git) package in your project and add the following to your `.csproj` file

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    [...]
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Configure your Build Pipeline to generate your Nuget package using the `dotnet pack` command. SourceLink doesn't work yet with the `Nuget pack` (based on my tests).

Push your changes to your Azure DevOps server and let the build pipeline generate your Nuget package and push it to your Nuget feed.

In Visual Studio go to  `tools -> Option -> Debugging -> General` and ensure that

- `Enable just my code` is **not checked**
- `Enable SourceLink support` **is checked**

Then in any other project, install your Nuget package.

When you'll try to step into some code defined in your package's DLL, Visual Studio will ask if you want to `Download source code and continue debugging`. It will authenticate to your Azure DevOps server using your Git credentials, download the source code, and let you debug it.